# Is it normal for a dog park visit to cause extra saliva/foam at the mouth?

Tags: dogs, socializing, dachshunds

Our dog, Peanut, is a 2 year old female Dachshund. We just recently took her for her first visit to a nearby dog park. We noticed that she had foam on her lips/jowls. I then realized visiting the dog park seems to cause her to create more saliva than usual.

On our next visit to the park, we paid closer attention, and sure enough, we had to wipe her mouth off a couple times. (Of course, we didn't really HAVE to, but you know what I mean.)

Is this salivating a normal physical response, or reaction, when visiting a social area, such as a leash-free dog park?

Comment: We just took her to the park for the first time this summer and wow, there must have been a lot of smells, for a minute there I thought our Dachshund was part Bulldog.

Comment: My Havanese puppy only drools at the dog park. I met another Havanese owner and his does the same thing. Not too sure what it means either but my dog loves to go to the park.

Comment: I have a dashshund/chihuahua mix and whenever we go to the dog park she also will drool a lot and seems to also get like a runny nose kinda. She's very social though and loves to go to the dog park. I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with dashshunds because I've notice this usually happens to that breed most often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty normal, our boys sometimes let it "rain" a bit under their mouths, if they smell other dogs.

Although I'm not sure about the actual "foam". This might be an overreaction of some kind, but overall it's really hard to judge, because for some "foam" starts at 1-2 bubbles.

If you're unsure, ask your vet.

Comment: Nah, she's not got rabies, it's really just a bubble or three... :) It just caught us by surprise is all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is normal *per se*, but it's surely not something to be concerned about. My dog, female, Dashshund X does not do it when she goes out.

There are many possible normal reasons for it to happen. Very often it's a bit of car sickness that starts the process. Other dogs will salivate when they see or smell food. Other dogs or people can also cause her to get very excited making it an adrenal response. Hormones from sniffing the urination of male dogs or female dogs on heat can also trigger this behaviour. All physiologically acceptable reasons.